# docker Bad Request ("swarm spec must be named "default"")

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I wrote a python script to initialize a docker swarm which works fine, except when I want to give a custom name to the swarm. The [documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swarm.html) mentions the 'name' attribute, but when I do

```
client = docker.from_env()
client.swarm.init(name="ddddd" , ....)
```

I get the following error message:

```
EXCEPTION: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/swarm/update?version=10&rotateWorkerToken=False&rotateManagerToken=False: Bad Request ("swarm spec must be named "default"")
```